# Getting write access violation when trying to re-allocate memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

I am writing a program that takes some contact information from user and grows the array dynamically when it gets full. But when I am trying to run the program I get Write access violation popping up a line from "iosfwd standard header". I don't know where I went wrong. Please do help.

My code looks like this:

```
# include "pch.h"
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Contact {
    string name;
    string number;
    string address;
    string exit;
};
void userPrompt(Contact &contact) {
    cout << "Name: ";
    getline(cin, contact.name);
    cout << "Phone number: ";
    getline(cin, contact.number);
    cout << "Address: ";
    getline(cin, contact.address);
    cout << "Exit? (y/n): ";
    getline(cin, contact.exit);
}
void printContact(Contact &contact) {
    cout << "Name: " << contact.name << endl;
    cout << "Phone number: " << contact.number << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << contact.address << "\n" << endl;
}
void growArray(int &currentLength, Contact *contacts) {
    int multiplyer = 2;
    Contact *new_array = new Contact[currentLength * multiplyer];
    for (int i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
        new_array[i] = contacts[i];
    }
    delete[] contacts;
    contacts = new_array;
    currentLength *= multiplyer;
}
void showAllContacts(Contact *contacts, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].name.length() != 0) {
            printContact(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
}
int main() {

    // Prompt the user to fill in the address book.
    // If the array gets full, make it bigger.

    Contact *contacts = new Contact[1];
    int currentLength = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        userPrompt(contacts[i]);
        if (contacts[i].exit == "y" or contacts[i].exit == "Y") {
            break;
        }
        i++;
        if (i == currentLength) {
            growArray(currentLength, contacts);
        }
    }

    // Show the address book

    showAllContacts(contacts, currentLength);
}
```

But when I am running the code it throws exception like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXZV8.png)

"Write Access Violation"
I think the bug is in the growArray function. But I can't fugure out where did I screw up. Please do help.

Comment: growArray should take a Contact** if you want to update the pointer in your main function. And you should pass &contacts when you call it from main

Comment: @Gojita No, `growArray` should have a `Contact*&`, not a `**`, that's a different contract. Anyway, OP should use a vector and not reimplement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
growArray(currentLength, contacts);
```

a *copy* of the pointer `contacts` is modified inside the function; but outside, the pointer's value stays the same. After `growArray` returns, `contacts` points to deleted memory, hence UB, hence the crash.

==> [Full program demonstration of the issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a37a6a5562fa063) <==

There are basically two solutions: the bad one and the good one. The bad one is to change the signature of `growArray` to take a reference to the pointer:

```
void growArray(int &currentLength, Contact *&contacts)
```

The good one is to stop this manually allocated memory non-sense and use a `std::vector<Contact>`!

Comment: But I am reassigning the contacts to the newArray immediately inside the growArray funciton. Isn't it supposed to work now? Look I am new to C++, if my question seems silly, I appologize. But what's the way around this situation ayway?

Comment: @AbusayeedRoni have you read the paragraph starting by "There are basically two solutions"?

Comment: @AbusayeedRoni Check the demonstration of the issue I've added to the answer.

Comment: yeah that works :) Thanks. But can you tell a bit about how *&contacts really work?

Comment: @AbusayeedRoni In your C++ book look at how parameters are passed to functions (hint they are *copied*), and then look up references and how that changes things.

Comment: @ john Thanks for the heads-up